# AWS NACL and RDP issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC spanning three availability zones with public subnets. Each AZ has one subnet. Each of these subnets uses an NACL that should allow only HTTP/HTTPS/RDS/SSH connections. I have one windows server running in each of the subnets to test.

I am using the following inbound rules:
[image]

and the following outbound rule which allows all outbound traffic
[image]

With this NACL setup I am able to RDP in to my instance. The minute I change my outbound rules to look like this where I changed outgoing connections from ALL to RDP only, I get a connection timeout:
[image]

Can anyone help me understand what is going on and why my RDP session fails here? I want to use this instance to RDP into other instances on the same subnet, without providing a blanket all outgoing traffic allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NACL enforces you to add ALLOW/DENY rule for ephermal ports. When a client makes a socket connection(RDP in your case), it provides an ephermal port on the client side to receive the response. The ephermal ports are randomly picked from a range depending on the operating system.

Here are the ranges mentioned in [AWS official documentation about ephermal port.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-ephemeral-ports)

> Many Linux kernels (including the Amazon Linux kernel) use ports
>   32768-61000
>
> Requests originating from Elastic Load Balancing use ports 1024-65535
>
> Windows operating systems through Windows Server 2003 use ports
>   1025-5000
>
> Windows Server 2008 and later versions use ports 49152-65535
>
> A NAT gateway uses ports 1024-65535
>
> AWS Lambda functions use ports 1024-65535

You need to add the NACL ALLOW rule for that range to have a predicted RDP session behavior.

Comment: That is a wide range of ports to keep open on the outbound side. Does it make sense then to just keep all outbound open?

Comment: Im connecting from a windows 10 pc. I used port range 1025-5000 and another rule with 49152-65535. There are no load balancers or nat gateways sitting between source and target here. Am I using the wrong port ranges?

Comment: It is a wide range, but it's only the ephemeral ports. You would still be blocking (outbound) traffic for all the system ports (0-1023) e.g. ssh, ftp, telnet etc